# My Player shivers on a game made with Ursina Python Engine

Tags: python, ursina

So I made a game on Ursina.
It works okay on a desktop.
However, when I play this game on laptop, the player shivers.
This disturbs the player to jump well

I tried to find a problem, but I actually failed.
Because the problem is repetitive, I thought that the issue might be in Update().
However, the code within Update() that pertains to the Player is primarily responsible for resetting the player's coordinates.

```
player = PlatformerController2d(
    texture = 'Player.png',
    scale = 1,
    position = (-14, -5),
    color = color.white,
)

player.jump_duration = 0.4
```

this is a code of Player Creation.

Rest of the code related to the player is for moving coordinates and changing textures.

Is this a problem of Ursina Engine? If it is, please let me know how to fix it

Comment: Are the versions the same between desktop and laptop pc?

Comment: are the resolutions different?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Yes, those are different. That might be the reason. Appreciate for your advice

Comment: @doneforaiur The desktop is Windows 10, and the laptop is Windows 11. If you are talking about the versions of Ursina, yes, they are the same

Comment: This is a bug with the collision logic in PlatformerController2d.

Comment: @pokepetter Is there any way to fix the bug?